# Node Inspector opens different file for breakpoints

Tags: node.js, debugging, node-inspector

I, cannot for the life of me, figure this one out.

Steps I took:

1. Run `node-inspector`
2. Run `node --debug server.js`
3. Navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858`
4. Assign a breakpoint
5. Run a command

What happens is, node-inspector will open a different window and highlight something else instead of the actual breakpoint I put. Putting `debugger` on the file doesn't help either.

Here are some screenshots to help clarify my question:
[image]
[image]

Strangely, enough this only happens when I'm on my windows machine. Testing this on a remote Linux server, it works as expected.

Any help very much appreciated here.